# Plain text in a MonoTouch Dialog Section?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I want to add some standalone description text into a MonoTouch `DialogViewControlle`r section. I started using a `MultilineElement`, but I need to get rid of the background of the section. Is this possible? I tried to make an `OwnerDrawnElement` but that looked dreadful (with a black background and not multiline):

```
    public override void Draw (RectangleF bounds, CGContext context, UIView view)
    {
        //UIColor.Clear.SetFill ();
        //context.FillRect (bounds);
        UIColor.White.SetColor ();  
        view.DrawString (this.Text, new RectangleF (10, 15, bounds.Width - 20, bounds.Height - 30), UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (14.0f), UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use a `Section` title to do so ?

I would look like the **Silent** and **Ring** text in this:
[image]

Another option is adding a `UIView` (and adding labels...) as an header (or footer). However this limits you to the top (or bottom) of the table.

Comment: I added a UIView and a label into a Section which worked nicely.